# Intent image from first activity to second activity and add text to that from Firebase database

Tags: android, android-studio, text, bitmap, png

I want intent image from first activity to second activity and add text to image from Firebase database and share it as a png.

Comment: You should not try with a bitmap. Think different and give us better info about what you have in the list

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. Check my edited question.